# GoogleAdMobAdsSdkAndroid-6.3.0 not working

Tags: android, admob

I've created some apps for the past last two weeks, and the admob ads is working perfectly.

Then, last week, when I published one app that has the ads in the app, I notice it was not working. The status said inactive (red circle) .

Then, I realized that there's already an updated version of AdsSDK which is 6.3 and my app is still using 6.2.1. But the ads are showing perfectly in the app.

So, what I did is just change the AdsSdk  (6.2.1 > 6.3) and update the app on Google Play (ver 2).

But, the ads are still not working. The status is still inactive on AdMob Dashboard.

Then, I also deleted the app profile on Admob, and created a new one with the same package name. 
And of course, I changed the mediation ID in the app, and updated a new version (ver 3.0) on Google Play.

And I don't think there is a problem in the code, used the same code as other apps which using adssdk 6.2.1 ...

What's the problem ?

Thank you :D

Comment: Have your tried running your app at all? Leave it running on your device(with test ads disabled) to activate the ads

Comment: Yes , I have already run it on my sister's phone .
My mom's phone as well ...

Comment: even though  the status is inactive, but in the Ad Network Mediation Placements , the impressions , requests and CTR is not 0 ..

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved ! :D
At the Ad Network Configuration Setting, 
I reliazed that the publisher id for the app was is different . So , I just changed it to the correct Publisher ID ..

Sorry for the unnecessary post ...
If someone has a problem like mine , try checking your AdMob Network setting ~ 
:D